# How to python subprocess from prompting password

Tags: python, passwords, subprocess

I am running a linux command using subprocess.Popen module in python.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["sudo","/usr/local/adduser"],shell=False,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

But that is prompting for password.

Is it possible to enter password with a python file? (I mean automatically)

Comment: Can you run the Python script with `sudo`?

Answer (score 3):

There are obvious reasons not to do that, but if you really want, you may use [pyexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) module to drive applications interacting with the *terminal* (e.g. programs asking passwords).

`sudo` can be configured not to ask a password, and it's probably a better solution for your specific example than storing any password in a file.

Comment: My work is to verify whether that is prompting for password or not..

Nothing else ........I will try with your solution